# What is the lalsuite and how can I use it?

Tags: general-relativity, computational-physics, software

I want to install the lalsuite package from https://git.ligo.org/lscsoft/lalsuite. How can I install it? How can I use it in Python? In "https://github.com/benjaminlackey/eosinference/commit/6577ec1dfa4375cfc4a898e531bf6cdbb0f6aa1a" has been used from this package to obtain the equation of state of neutron star. I want to use this package similar to this code. But I can not install it.

Comment: Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

Comment: This package is used about equation of state a neutron star and this code is about the properties of neutron star. I want only know how I can use this package for eos of neutron star.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Such questions are off-topic here. Your question is clearly about a specific package and a specific language.

Comment: @minaahmadi I would recommend to read the documentation carefully: https://docs.ligo.org/lscsoft/lalsuite/